# F# locking - thread wakes up but doesn't continue its work

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, f#

I have this problem with concurrency in F#. This is the shortened version of my code (pretty much like pseudo-code)

What it does is that, every thread is required to do the running, only if it is allowed to i.e. status <> Waiting. Every thread has its own next threads await to do the running when it is done. So basically when the current thread returns the result, it pass the job to the next thread to start doing the running to.

```
type Test
    // ... A BUNCH MEMBERS
    // THIS IS THE MAIN ONE
    member this.Running =
         // (A):  IF STATUS = WAITING -> WAIT UNTIL ALLOW TO RUN
         lock this <| fun () ->
              while this.GetStatus = Waiting do ignore(Monitor.Wait this)
              Monitor.PulseAll this

         // (B): EXECUTE RUNING
         let result = this.DoRunning()

         // (C): PASS WORK TO NEXT THREAD IN QUEUE
         let nextThread = this.GetNextWaiter
         nextThread.ChangeStatus()

         // **PROBLEM: AT THIS POINT, THE THREAD THAT'S WAITING ABOVE 
         // SHOULD WAKE UP AND DO THE JOB I.E. EXECUTE RUNNING

         // (D): RETURN RESULT OF THIS THREAD
         result.Value
```

The problem of this code is that, when the current thread pass the work (C) to the next thread (i.e. changing next thread's status to something other than waiting), that next thread should be waken up from its "sleeping" mode at (A) and start executing the job from (B).

My current attempt to solve it is not bright. What I do is to force `nextThread` to run the method when it's waken up by adding `nextThread.Running` just before (D). By this wait, there's some collision occurred with the thread itself.

Is there any way I could make the waiting thread to execute the following code when it wakes up?

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but have you considered using F# agents instead of threads? They are much easier to work with and reason about and let you express such coordination in a significantly easier way. As a starting point, see: http://www.developerfusion.com/article/139804/an-introduction-to-f-agents/

Comment: I wish I could - this is part of my uni project and we're not allowed to use anything other than just threads/lock/monitor.

Comment: I see, that makes sense :-) I was getting seriously worried that someone wants to use threads in a real system!